# hibernate.cfg.xml failing to recognize mappings directory

Tags: xml, hibernate, intellij-idea

Following instructions from a separate post, I configured the hibernateMappings directory to be a resources root (as indicated by the pattern in the lower right of the directory icon):

[image]

However, the hibernate.cfg.xml file is still failing to recognize the directory:

[image]

EDIT: Here is the Employee.hbm.xml file as it currently appears (with an unresolved class and associated properties, as I've not yet written the class file):

[image]

As you can imagine, I'd like to keep my mappings in a separate directory, so I was hoping someone may know what I'm overlooking.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files at the root of your project aren't in the classpath. This means not accessible by the Java programm.

Usually, the following directories are in the classpath :

- src/main/java
- src/main/resources
- src/main/webapps
- ...

I advice to move your file **hibernate.cfg.xml** and **hibernateMapping** **directory** in **src/main/resources** and it should be accessible by the program.